# Reset first select list when second one is reset to 0

Tags: javascript, html, list, select

I've got some example code, what I want is when the value in the second select list is set to 0 the first one also resets to 0, at the moment they reset each other when a value is selected in one. Any help appreciated thanks:

HTML:

```
<select name="Standard" id="std" size="6" onClick="selectCheck(this,'del'); return true;"> 
     <option value="0">Select one</option> 
     <option value="Eggs" selected>Eggs</option> 
     <option value="Bacon">Bacon</option> 
     <option value="Toast">Toast</option> 
     <option value="Ham">Ham</option> 
     <option value="Home">Home Fries</option> 
     <option value="Jelly">Jelly</option> 
</select> 
<select name="Deluxe" id="del" size="6" onClick="selectCheck(this,'std'); return true;"> 
     <option value="0">Select one</option> 
     <option value="Omelet">Omelet</option> 
     <option value="Canadian">Canadian Bacon</option> 
     <option value="Muffin">Muffin</option> 
     <option value="Steak">Steak</option> 
     <option value="Cottage">Cottage Fries</option> 
     <option value="Preserves">Preserves</option> 
</select>
```

JS:

```
function selectCheck(me,other) { 
    var ind = me.selectedIndex; 
    if (ind > 0) { 
       document.getElementById(other).selectedIndex = 0; 
    } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for the specific ID

```
if (ind > 0 && other !='del') { 
  document.getElementById(other).selectedIndex = 0; 
 }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3PKL2/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="Standard" id="std" size="6"> 
<option value="0">Select one</option>
 <option value="Eggs" selected>Eggs</option>
<option value="Bacon">Bacon</option> 
<option value="Toast">Toast</option> 
<option value="Ham">Ham</option> 
<option value="Home">Home Fries</option> 
<option value="Jelly">Jelly</option> </select>
 <select name="Deluxe" id="del" size="6" onClick="selectCheck(this,'std'); return true;"> 
<option value="0">Select one</option> 
<option value="Omelet">Omelet</option> 
<option value="Canadian">Canadian Bacon</option>
 <option value="Muffin">Muffin</option>
 <option value="Steak">Steak</option> 
<option value="Cottage">Cottage Fries</option> 
<option value="Preserves">Preserves</option> 
</select>
<script>
function selectCheck(me,other) { var ind = me.selectedIndex; if (ind<1) { document.getElementById(other).selectedIndex = 0; } }
</script>
```